# How to send predefined/canned SMS/iMessages?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, template

Is there a way to prepare predefined/canned messages in order to quickly send them by SMS/iMessage on the iPhone or iPad? I find myself quite often using the same 4-5 templates:

- *I'm in a meeting, I will call you later!*
- *I'm on my way*
- *Ok, drop me an email!*
- *Is it a good time to talk?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Keyboard shortcuts.

Go to

> Settings • General • Keyboard • Shortcuts

From there, you can add shortcuts, like `omw` for "On my way."

[image: ios5 shortcuts]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's now 2016 and Apple still don't provide an easy way to do this, but one option would be to try [Tap Tap Send](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tap-tap-send/id460772454?mt=8&at=1010l3Is&ct=SO). I built the app a few years ago to solve this exact same problem, and have recently given it some much needed TLC.

With Tap Tap Send you simply bookmark the people you message the most, then enter the messages you might want to send them. Now, next time you need to fire off a quick message just: Tap to select a person, Tap to select a message, Tap send, and you're done.

Here's a bit more about it — [website](http://www.EighteenDegrees.com/TapTapSend/), or check it out on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tap-tap-send/id460772454?mt=8&at=1010l3Is&ct=SO).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own template by going to settings, general, keyboards then click on text replacement. There you can create a shortcut and what you want it to say!

Answer (score 0):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smsy/id1009761842?mt=8

This app answers you really well :)
I personally built it for this use. 
I hope apple makes more entries in the future.

Comment: Please give a brief summary of what the app does.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Texts is the perfect app to fit your need :

- Thanks to iCloud, keep your messages up to dates on all your devices.
- Get your messages at hand with the Texts iMessage extension.
- Add new messages to your list from application and also through the iOS share extension.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/texts/id1401953728?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This post doesn't identify you as the creator of the software and, therefore, is could be in violation of the [site rules on self-promotion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).  - From Review